Нужна ли запятая после "десятый"?
Нынешний, десятый, фестиваль будет проходить на родине.

Правильно:
Нынешний, десятый фестиваль будет проходить на родине.
Пояснение

По семантике десятый — пояснительное определение (можно вставить слова ТО ЕСТЬ или А ИМЕННО), но обособления нет. Между определениями ставится запятая, как при однородных отношениях, произношение также соответствующее.

Тема регулируется правилом Розенталя, пункт 2, примечание 2
2. Определения, носящие характер пояснения (перед ними 
можно поставить слова а именно, то есть и т. п.), 
отделяются запятой от поясняемого слова, но после них 
запятая не ставится: Торчали толстые головни, остатки 
прежней, сгоревшей бани (М. Г.); В романе показаны 
старые, исчезающие и новые, зарождающиеся явления 
общественной жизни; Все усилия необходимо было 
сосредоточить на одном, северном направлении; Очередной, 
шестой том подписного издания на днях поступит в магазин; 
Он заговорил совсем другим, серьёзным тоном. 


Обособление одиночных определений обычно не делается,  Чаще обособляются различные обороты речи. Сравнить (у Розенталя):


Четвёртая, последняя часть романа завершится эпилогом. — Четвёртая, по-видимому последняя, часть романа завершится эпилогом.

Спасибо! А если скажем; Нынешний, десятый по счёту (?) фестиваль будет проходить на родине. Тут нужна запятая в указанном месте?

Да, обособление нужно. Это оборот, к тому же у него значение дополнительной информации. Интонационно это сообщение второго плана речи.  Таким образом, мы ориентируемся на структурный и семантический факторы.  Между однородными и пояснительными определениями  нет принципиальной разницы,  что делает возможным выбор.  Но следует учитывать все: смысл, структурную грамматику, правила по теме. Решение можно проверить по интонации: читается/не читается.

Обычно при перечислении определений в предложении запятую не ставят после последнего. То есть будет "нынешний, десятый фестиваль".
Мне кажется, в Вашем случае так могло бы быть только если толковать "десятый" как вводное слово. Если у него значение в предложении вторичное и несколько пренебрежительное, тогда можно его запятыми отделить. Но если одинаково важно, что фестиваль и нынешний, и десятый, тогда делать этого не стоит. А решать, "важно" ли это или нет, это Вам)

Если десятый не имеет одинаковый вес в предложении, как нынешний, прилагательное тоже можно поместить в скобки: "нынешний (десятый) фестиваль", "нынешний фестиваль (десятый)".
